# Como remover números de uma string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, deve ser algo fácil, mas eu estou quebrando a cabeça para resolver.

Tenho uma string, `String(ValorTotal).replace("." , ""); //tira ponto`
Essa string me retorna o seguinte valor: `23600000000000004`
O que eu preciso é, remover esses números `0000000000004` e deixar apenas os `2360`.

Se alguém souber, me ajude!

Comment: Qual é a regra para a separação? Queres somente os primeiros 4 numeros? ou todos os numeros antes de X zeros seguidos? ou a parte inteira de um numero? Explica melhor para podermos ajudar.

Comment: Qual valor original de `ValorTotal`?

Comment: @Sergio quero apenas os primeiros 4 números.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr seria isso, var ValorTotal = ValorDis + ValorDur, que seria o valor da distancia mais o valor da duração.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para capturar somente os 4 primeiros dígitos, basta usar a função [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

```
var valor = String(ValorTotal).replace("." , "");
valor.substr(0, 4); // Captura do primeiro ao quarto dígito.
```

Comment: Isso me ajudou, você pode me ajudar nisso, tenho esse código,  ValorTotal.toFixed(2), tem vez que o código vem assim 2.80, e outras vezes assim, 6.000, então nesse toFixed, eu queria trocar para quando for 6.000 trocar o 2 por 3.

Comment: Você pode colocar uma condição nesse caso. `var toFixed = 2; if (valor == 6000) { toFixed = 3 }; ValorTotal.toFixed(toFixed);`

Comment: Acho que não vai dar certo.

Comment: Se possível abre uma nova pergunta ou cria uma sala de bate papo que poderemos ver melhor a questão, caso contrário os comentários poderão ser removidos depois. Essa parte do código você pode postar aqui mesmo no StackOverflow ou Codepen, por exemplo.

Comment: Onde cria uma sala de bate papo?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/

Comment: entra nessa https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70759/ajuda-if-else

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70769/discussion-between-valdeir-psr-and-matheus-calixto).